# Why Line Height has difference between Development and Production (ReactJS, TailwindCSS)

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

[Development: Everything works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd6xx.png)

[Production: there is extra pixels (UNWANTED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNs2E.png)

[Using **TailwindCSS **in **ReactJS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuHyO.png)

***How to remove the Unwanted extra height pixels***

...........................................................
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66300511/tailwindcss-css-and-fonts-are-not-working-on-production](https://stackoverflow.com)

Can it be the solution? Trying now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.